# Polynomial algebra and its special ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Consider a polynomial algebra $A=\mathbb{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and its ideal $I$, such that $A/I=\mathbb{K}[y_1,\ldots, y_k]$. Is it true that there exist new polynomial generators $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ (in a sense that $A=\mathbb{K}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$) such that $I=(z_1,\ldots,z_{n-k})$?

Comment: It's unclear in general what "such $A/I=K[y_1,\dots,y_k]$ means: does it mean that $A/I$ is generated by $k$ elements, or that it's *freely* generated by $k$ elements (i.e., is isomorphic to a polynomial algebra over $k$ indeterminates). Given the context it certainly means *freely* generated. Also "new variables" should be "elements".

Comment: Variables are elements that are part of a set of polynomial generators.

Comment: It means that $y_i$ are algebraically independent. By variables I mean a part of independent generators of polynomial algebra.

Comment: No, you don't mean that: $x^2$ and $y^2$ are algebraically independent but they are not "variables"...

Comment: See if my edit is OK

Comment: You are right. In my comment I used that if some independent elements generate algebra, then they must be its variables

Comment: The general situation (independent of the characteristic of the base field) is, it is true when $n\geq k+2$ in your notation and not known in general otherwise and as @BugsBunny pointed out, false in positive characteristic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called the Embedding Problem. I believe that it is false in positive characteristics and unknown in characteristic zero, except a few small cases. See [Kraft's review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1423629)
for the extent of my knowledge of the state of the problem. The counterexample in characteristic $p$ is from this paper:
$$
K[x,y]/(y^{p^2}-x-x^{2p}) 
$$